# Node.js - "Cannot find module", when the module call other module

Tags: node.js

I'm developing my first Node.js App. and Everything is find, but Now the app is getting bigger. and I'd like to divide the app into different files. So,  I used a "require" method to divide a app into files.

but My App display "Cannot find module".

```
** Call Ordering **
A.js is call B.js <-- call is ok
B.js is call C.js <-- Cannot Find module, B.js can't call 'test222 function'
```

My Sample Code.

a.js

```
...    
var m=require('./controller/b.js');
m.register(req,res);
```

b.js

```
exports.register=function(){
var MyModule=require('./model/c.js');
console.log(MyModule.test222());  <--------- cannot find module
};
```

c.js

```
exports.test222=function() {
    return "c.js";

};
```

Help me or advice. thank you.
I want to Call module in another module. but My Node App is not working for "cannot find module". How to solve it?

Comment: in what folders are a.js, b.js and c.js located?

Comment: 'a.js' is located in './'

Comment: Did you intend for a.js to be in /controller?

Comment: Sorry, I wrote code incorrectly, I just edit. I intend for a.js to be in '/'

Comment: Is your model folder located in your controller folder?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that you've mistyped by writing `var m=require('./controller/a.js');` instead of `var m=require('./controller/b.js');`

If so, I can see that you have the following file structure:

```
./a.js
./controller/b.js
./model/c.js
```

So you run `./a.js` which requires `./controller/b.js` and it works fine. But when `./controller/b.js` requires `./model/c.js`, Node resolves `c.js` as `./controller/model.js`, because [each module is relative to the file calling `require()`](http://nodejs.org/api/modules.html#modules_file_modules).

This is why error occurs.

To solve this problem you should replace

```
var MyModule=require('./model/c.js');
```

with

```
var MyModule=require('../model/c.js');
```

Answer (score 0):

the require function automatically search for modules at the node_modules folder
by just typing the name of the module with the js. extension

```
var b=require('b.js');
var c=require('c.js');
```

but if you make changes to the structure of your node_modules folder you need to navigate to your moduleusing the relative waie  by taping

```
"../"
```

to navigate from a child directory to the parent directory and

```
 "./"
```

to navigate from the parent directory to the child directory
You need to respect the relative way.